# best aproach to check if xml is part of a pdf document in Java

Tags: java, xml, pdf

I want to check if a pdf file contains a long string, which is a string of a full XML document.

I can open both files and extract the text already. i've done that with the following code:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-pdf", ".tmp");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
out.write(Base64.decodeBase64(testObject.getPdfAsDoc().getContent()));
out.close();
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(temp);
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String pdfText = pdfStripper.getText(document);
Integer posS =pdfText.indexOf("<?xml version");
Integer posE = pdfText.lastIndexOf("</ServiceSpecificationSchema:serviceSpecification>")+"</ServiceSpecificationSchema:serviceSpecification>".length();
pdfText =pdfText.substring( posS,posE );
String xmlText = testObject.getXmlAsDoc().getContent();
```

Now i have the problem, that the lines of both documents don't match, a cause of formats like linebreaks from the pdf file.

Example lines of TXT output from XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceSpecificationSchema:serviceSpecification xmlns:xs="  ..... >
```

Example lines of TXT output from PDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceSpecificationSchema:serviceSpecification
xmlns:xs="  ..... >
```

Second, i have page numbers between the XML tags from the PDF. Do you know a good way to remove this lines?

```
</operations>
Page 51 of 52
</consumerInterface>
```

What is the best approach to check if the pdf contains an XML?

I've already tried to remove all linebreaks and whitespaces from the file and compare them. But if i do that, i cannot find a line with the difference. 
It does not have to be a valid XML file at the end.

Comment: You could apply the same formatting function to both the PDF file and the string you're looking for.

Comment: As it does not need to remain valid XML, remove all whitespace: `s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` and then use `contains`. Take care of page breaks with a spurious page number. So maybe use splitted parts.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply! I've updated my question to give more information about what i've already tried and what i want to have at the end.

Comment: You may want to use the `PDFTextStripperByArea` instead of `PDFTextStripper` and with it restrict the page area from which you extract text to exclude headers and footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to post my solution if others need it.

My code is a little to large, to post it here.

Basicly i extract the text from the pdf and remove strings like page x and headlines from it. After that i removed all whitespaces as pointed out above. Finally i compare character by character of the extracted string to inform my users where they have done things wrong in the text. This method works pretty well, even if the auther does not care about formatting and just copy and paste the whole xml document.